# how to query dict inside is list in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

here is a document example:

```
Person:{
_id:xxx,
age:15,
sex:male,
education:{
  "level1":["l1t1","l1t2",...],
  "level2":["xxx1","xxx2",...],
  "level3":["test1","test2",...]
 }
}
```

Now I know one of the value of level1, and one of the value of level3. How to query these two value ? 
I tried to query such as
`{"education":{"level1":the value1 I got,"level3":the value2 I got}}`
but it return nothing
So, how to write query dict for this question?  It's a dict ,but it contains list....

Answer (score 0):

Use Mongo's [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

```
{"education.level1": value1, "education.level3": value3}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. education is not a document field, so it can't use dot notation.